# In Python 3.x, is it legal to specify non-classes as base classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, language-lawyer

Here's an example:

```
>>> def magic(name, bases, dct):
...     print(repr(bases))
...     return type(name, (object,), dct)
... 
>>> class Foo('hello world!', metaclass=magic):
...     pass
... 
('hello world!',)
>>> Foo
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Foo.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
>>>
```

I'm particularly interested in the `class` statement.  While this does appear to work, I can't find any specific endorsement of this technique in the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions).  The "advanced uses" language probably refers to the use of keyword arguments (e.g. `metaclass=`), rather than positional arguments.  I'd like to know whether this works by accident or by design.

It does fail with a rather interesting `TypeError` if the metaclass is a subclass of `type`, as discussed [elsewhere in the reference](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass):

```
>>> class Meta(type):
...     def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
...         print(repr(bases))
...         bases = (object,)
...         return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)
...     def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
...         super().__init__(name, (object,), dct)
... 
>>> class Foo('hello world!', metaclass=Meta):
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
>>>
```

To summarize: **When (if ever) is it legal to pass non-classes as base classes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is slightly mis-stated: if the inheritance objects (bases) are not classes, they are not 'base classes'.  The language doc section on compound statements: class says

> The inheritance list usually gives a list of base classes

'Usually' anticipates the possibility that the bases are not classes.  Having said this, the doc seems to proceed on the assumption that the bases *are* classes and can be called 'base classes'.

Your example shows that the possibility can be realized.  The Data Model: Customizing Class Creation section (3.3.3 in 3.4) on "advanced uses" gives detail on how the class statement works.  The relevant steps are the first, determining the metaclass and the last, calling the metaclass.

I find 3.3.3.1, "Determining the appropriate metaclass" a bit unclear. The first rule

> if no bases and no explicit metaclass are given, then type() is used

does not apply to either of your examples.  The second rule

> if an explicit metaclass is given and it is not an instance of type(),
>   then it is used directly as the metaclass

appears to apply to your first example.  But I wonder if 'instance' should be 'subclass' or 'instance or subclass'.  Otherwise, this would seem to apply to your second example, but it does not.  The third rule

> if an instance of type() is given as the explicit metaclass, or bases are defined, then the most derived metaclass is used

must include subclasses of type() and not (just?) 'instances', as we know it was applied to your second example.  The second clause ("or bases ..." would seem to make it apply to your first example, but I am sure it does not.

The current definitive answer to class creation should be in the type object [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7d826a6b92a1/Objects/typeobject.c).  The error message comes from line 2265.

Comment: "But I wonder if 'instance' should be 'subclass' or 'instance or subclass'. Otherwise, this would seem to apply to your second example, but it does not.": I disagree, actually.  An "instance of `type`" is just a class, which the second example uses.  `isinstance(Meta, type)` returns `True`.

Comment: `Meta` is defined as a subclass of `type`.  But since type is both a subclass *and* an instance of itself (which I forgot), Meta is *also* an instance of type.  So the instance check is actually 'instance or subclass' as *normally* understood.